# how can I load a full webpage from a different domain through PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a program using PHP where I can load a full webpage and navigate the site while still staying in a different domain. The problem I'm having is that I can't load things like stylesheets and images because they are relative links. I need a way to make the relative links in to absolute links.

Right now I can get just plain HTML from the page using this handy bit of code:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://tumblr.com');
```

I can't use an iframe to display the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but you must set `allow_url_fopen` to `on` before running it.

```
echo file_get_contents('http://othersiteurl.com');
```

You may also use cURL. Example:

```
function get_data($url, $timeout = 5) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Slightly modified code from: https://davidwalsh.name/curl-download